# finding 5 random numbers combinations except a some set of combinations

Tags: javascript, random

I am writing a code which generates 5 random numbers (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5) such that 
1<=n1<=4, 1<=n2<=6, 1<=n3<=8, 1<=n4<=12, 1<=n5<=20,

except these combinations:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 5],
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

approaches i am thinking:

1. generate random numbers then check it from the set of invalid combinations, if present generate again.
2. generate each number of 5 numbers like below

```
if ((noOfOnes === 1 && noOfTwos === 3) || (noOfOnes === 2 && noOfTwos === 2) || (noOfTwos === 4)) {
    var min = 3;
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperRanges[t] + 1 - min) + min);
    inputNumbers.push(num);
}
```

approach 1 may take time as the situation may occurs when cosecutive invalid combinations are getting generated.

so any help regarding approach 2, or any other approach you can suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Use approach 1. There are over 46,000 possible sequences, and only 10 of them are invalid. So the chance of getting one of the invalid sequences is only 0.02%. The chance of getting them twice in a row is only 0.0004%. So you'll practically never have to try more than twice to get a valid sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You could get random values and check against the exclude values and create a new array if one of the exclude array is found.

```js
const
    getRandom = (ranges, exclude) => {
        let temp;            
        do temp = ranges.map(v => Math.floor(Math.random() * v) + 1);
        while (exclude.some(a => a.every((v, i) => temp[i] === v)))
        return temp;
    },
    exclude = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],
    ranges = [4, 6, 8, 12, 20];
    
console.log(getRandom(ranges, exclude));
```

Comment: Isn't this what he described in approach 1? He didn't ask how to do it, he just asked for advice on which approach to use.